# Hide stderr and pipe stdout in tcsh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csh, tcsh

How can I hide stderr but use stdout in csh script?

I'm trying to find occurrences in some file which may exist or not, and act according to the result:

```
if (`grep phrase file | wc -l` > 0) then
    echo 'Match!'
endif
```

The problem is that if the file does not exist an error is shown on the console.

I found how to drop stderr and redirect stdout to console (according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35715/stderr-redirection-not-working-in-csh):

```
`(grep phrase file | wc -l > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null
```

But it doesn't work in my case because I want to use the result in the script.

I thought about replacing `/dev/tty` in a temporary file and use its content, but I wonder if there is a solution without temporary file.

Another way is to use bash from my csh script:

```
if (`echo 'grep phrase file 2> /dev/null' | sh | wc -l`) then
    echo 'Match!'
endif
```

But this may complicate the script if the grep command is more complex, e.g. when using variable the below command is not going to work as-is:

```
if (`echo 'grep $phrase file 2> /dev/null' | sh | wc -l`) then
    echo 'Match!'
endif
```

Thus I prefer csh pure solution.

How can I do that in pure csh?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in csh shells, and your solution with piping the command to sh is **exactly** what occurred to me.  You can get the variables to substitute if you use double guotes (") instead of single quotes (') around the grep.

Comment: Does using double quotes fix the problem with not expanding the variable?

Comment: I didn't check it, actually my case is much more complex than the simple variable problem I showed here. I'm afraid that publishing the whole case here will make the question and answers too complex and unusable. I just wanted to show the principle of why I prefer using csh instead redirecting to bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can close standard error by just suffixing **2>&-** to the command.

If C shell (in particular) complains about that syntax (I don't honestly recall, and I don't see it in the surprisingly incomplete "reference manual"), then do it by the old Swiss army knife technique, that is, **2>/dev/null**.  That's what /dev/null is there for: it's an entry point into the memory device driver that merely discards the data written to it.

Comment: '2>/dev/null' is not working for c-shell !

Answer (score 1):

Use a FIFO to redirect stdout off stderr.

```
mkfifo ~/fifo
( grep phrase file > ~/fifo & ) >& /dev/null
if ( "`wc -l < ~/fifo`" > 0 ) echo 'Match\!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [another method](https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=493) I found.

```
if ( "`( ( grep phrase file > /dev/fd/0 ) >& /dev/null < /dev/fd/1 ) | wc -l`" > 0 ) echo 'Match\!'
```

Note file descriptors as files aren't POSIX-compliant, though existent on most SVID (System V) and BSD-compliant systems.

If you want the script POSIX-compliant, the `mkfifo` method is preferable.

Comment: All this to demonstrate yet again why every sane person has abandoned `csh` and its descendants decades ago.

Answer (score -1):

you can just check that file exists before grep it. Also grep has -c option to show amount of finding, so wc also is not required:

[ -n file ] && grep "phrase" file && echo 'Match!'

Comment: This is not valid csh syntax.

Comment: (Because there's no command separator between the `]` and the `then`, it's not even valid POSIX/Bourne syntax).

Comment: The regular `sh` syntax without the [useless `grep -c`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc) would be simply `if grep -sq phrase file; then echo 'Match!'`; fi`